# FlatList- rentered children count finding

Tags: react-native

How to find children of flatlist. i.e. We want to find how many items rendered using FlatList.
We are able to use Flatlist for rendering total 15 items on screen. Now, we want to get how many items are rendered on screen (15) using programmetically. So here how to access FlatList component in typescript and get number of childrens.

Comment: flatlist needs a list in its "data" prop, cant you get the number of items by just the length of this list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RohitSK, we can get length from data props, but we dont want to do that. because once we get total number of items rendered, then we want to access each item independently based on index of item and perform some actions on them. So we want to do all these steps programmetically.